# Using jQuery to select a class that occurs more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So I have a list of items from a database which I have iterated through, and I made each item a modal where the user can edit each item, such as `item->name, item->colour, item-title` etc.

Each `<input></input>` has a class `edit-title` for the title, and `edit-name` for the name, and so on.

Since I'm using ajax to send this information to my database I have to use jQuery, so I know how to do this if it was one button that occurred once, but not multiple times.

Here is what I'm using to get the data:

```
var title = $('.e-title').val();
var id = $('.e-id').val();
var subject = $('.e-class').val();
var date = $('.e-due').val();
var description = $('.e-description').val();
```

But every time, only the first nth-child() gets picked, no matter which button I press. How would I maybe find the closest instances of those classes for jQuery to pick up?

HTML

```
<div class="e-modal-form">

        <label id="e-id" style="display:none;" class="e-id"> {{ $assignment->id }} </label>
        <h5>Title</h5> <input class="form-control e-title" type="text" value="{{ $assignment->title }}"/> <br>
        <h5>Subject<h5> <select class="form-control e-class" value="{{ $assignment->class }}"> <option> e.g. Chemistry @foreach([1,2,3,4] as $num) <option> {{$num}} </option> @endforeach </select> <br>
        <h5>Due Date</h5> <input class="form-control e-due" type="date" min="2016-01-02" value="{{ $assignment->created_at->format('Y-m-d') }}"> <br>
        <h5>Description</h5> <textarea class="form-control e-description" rows="4">{{ $assignment->description }}</textarea>
        <button class="e-btn-edit e-btn e-update-button">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span> Save
        </button>

      </div>
```

My updateAssignment Function

```
function updateAssignment()
{

  var $container = $(this).closest('.e-modal-form');
  var title = $container.find('.e-title').val();
  var id = $container.find('.e-id').val();
  var subject = $container.find('.e-class').val();
  var date = $container.find('.e-due').val();
  var description = $container.find('.e-description').val();

  alert(title);

  $.get('/updateAssignment', {title: title, id: id, class: subject, date: date, description: description}, function()
  {


  });



}
```

How I'm trying to call it from the `document.ready` handler

```
$('.e-update-button').click(function() {

      updateAssignment();

 });
```

Comment: You need to use DOM traversal from the button which is clicked, but we need to see your HTML to show you how to reach those elements. Can you please edit your question to include it.

Comment: I have updated my question @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: You could try to add table id's to the id of the input? <input id="subject_33" />/

Comment: Worth mentioning that while the two (current) answers to the question use ".closest(..)", you could also use ".parent(..)" in this instance depending on your goals. See the jQuery docs for more info.

Comment: @SeanClark true, although `closest()` is preferred as it is more rigid; should the structure of your HTML change then the JS will still work (assuming the selectors remained the same)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan agreed, I do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you can traverse the DOM from the button which was clicked to get the relevant inputs within the same div container. Try this:

```
$('.e-btn-edit').click(function() {
    var $container = $(this).closest('.e-modal-form');
    var title = $container.find('.e-title').val();
    var id = $container.find('.e-id').val();
    var subject = $container.find('.e-class').val();
    var date = $container.find('.e-due').val();
    var description = $container.find('.e-description').val();

    // work with the values here...
});
```

If the modal div is appended to the DOM after the page is loaded, then you would need to use a delegated event handler on the button, like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.e-btn-edit', function() {
    // the rest of the above code...
});
```

*Update*

Given the logic flow in your update question, you need to amend your code like this:

```
function updateAssignment() {
    var $container = $(this).closest('.e-modal-form');
    var title = $container.find('.e-title').val();
    var id = $container.find('.e-id').val();
    var subject = $container.find('.e-class').val();
    var date = $container.find('.e-due').val();
    var description = $container.find('.e-description').val();

    // work with the values here...
});

$('.e-btn-edit').click(updateAssignment);
```

Comment: If I do `$('.e-update-button').click(function() {

      updateAssignment();

    });` where I have your first chunk of code exactly, it returns `undefined`, but if I place your code in the `$(document).ready();` it works fine, how do I make it work in a function?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; event handlers in jQuery have to go inside the `document.ready` handler

Comment: I have a function `updateAssignment();` where I put `var $container = $(this).closest('.e-modal-form');
    var title = $container.find('.e-title').val();
    var id = $container.find('.e-id').val();
    var subject = $container.find('.e-class').val();
    var date = $container.find('.e-due').val();
    var description = $container.find('.e-description').val();`, when i `alert(title)`, it returns as `undefined`

Comment: That's because you need to pass the reference of the button to the `updateAssignment()` function as the scope of the `this` keyword has changed.

Comment: How would I do that? Just a normal parameter?

Comment: I don't know as you've not shown enough information. Again you need to include all the relevant code in the question.

Comment: I have updated my question, I hope that's what you needed

Comment: Thankyou very much for your help, you have taught me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to traverse back to the parent which holds all the elements, And from there find all the required element and extract the value. The code would be like below

```
$('.e-btn').on('click',function(){
     var $parentDiv = $(this).closest('div.e-modal-form');

     var title = $parentDiv.find('.e-title').val();
     var id = $parentDiv.find('.e-id').val();
     var subject = $parentDiv.find('.e-class').val();
     var date = $parentDiv.find('.e-due').val();
     var description = $parentDiv.find('.e-description').val();

     //your stuff here
    });
```